# ASP.NET Website - When does session get reset

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

For an ASP.NET Website where i am making updates. What would cause user sessions to reset?

From my understanding if i make any changes to files in the app_code folder or the global.asax file it will reset everyone's session but if i made a change to .cs file (in the top directory) it wont reset everyone's session?

Would it reset the session of anyone that was on that page that i updated?

Can someone help me with my understanding, thank you.

Comment: It maybe a problem with the server version and the application pool was changed to .net4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming memory-based session (as opposed to sql server based).

Well, the app pool restart will blow out session.
(so, in some cases even un-handled errors will blow out session).

Modify web config?

- that will case app pool to restart (and blow out session).

Update any folder outside of app_data. Again, app pool re-start (and blows out session).

change content of bin folder - again app pool re-starts, (and blows out session).

Update code behind (.cs, or vb pages (code behind)). - again, app pool re-starts, (and blows out session). (so anything that will cause a re-compile of code).

There are probably a good many more - the above is a basic list.

You can thus consider adopting sql session based, and that will thus be far more robust, and I even re-started IIS services, and users if not doing anything just looking at their web page while logged on? They were able to continue working even after a full re-start of IIS services.

On the other hand, I now always use a asp.net web site "applcation". Thus no souce code is placed on the web server, and my compile is done with visual studio before deploying. The only big issue is that if you change to a application deployment model, the even just changing one line of code behind will force/require a full re-publish of the web site.

It looks like you are using a web site, and thus source code (code behind) is placed on the web server. Thus, IIS has the job of re-compiling such code, and thus any code change will as a general rule cause a app_pool re-start, and thus loss of session.

As noted, if you change from in-memory session to SQL server based (turn that feature on), then most if not all of your session issues will go away. Even if you not using "application deployment" and have/use code behind on the site for IIS to re-compile? Then using sql server-based session management should fix all of your session() woes.